# How to write functions/definitions such that to render in HTML templates Django?

Tags: python, django, view, django-templates

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

CHOICES = (('Earned Leave','Earned Leave'),('Casual Leave','Casual Leave'),('Sick Leave','Sick Leave'),('Paid Leave','Paid Leave'))

class Leave(models.Model):

    employee_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null =True)
    type_of_leave = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = CHOICES)
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import LeaveRequestForm
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .models import Leave
...
def leaveRequest(request):
form_class = LeaveRequestForm

if request.method == "POST":
    form = LeaveRequestForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        leave = form.save(commit = False)
        leave.user = request.user
        form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/thanks/")
else:
    return auto_fill_form(request)
def leaves_sick(request):
    data = Leave.objects.filter(employee_ID = request.user.username)
    sl = "sg"
    for obj in data:
        if obj.type_of_leave == 'Sick Leave':
            sl += obj.date_diff
    return render(request, "status.html",{'sl':data})
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea, DateInput
from lrequests.models import Leave

class LeaveRequestForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        fields = ("name",  "type_of_leave", "from_date", "to_date")
        model = Leave
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name='lrequests'

urlpatterns = [
    path('lrequests/',views.leaveRequest, name = 'request'),
    path('status/', views.get_data, name = 'status'),
    path('status/', views.leaves_sick, name = 'sick'),


]
```

Basically, this is a function that works on employee attendance, type of leaves etc. If an employee requests for a leave with type as 'el' (Earned leave), I need to return how many times in the past he has requested for earned leaves from the database (assuming there are more than one requests from the user in the db)

I'm working on "leave management system". I need to know how many time a user has requested for a leave. Initially a user sends a leave request form to the admin with ModelForms. There are leave types like "earned_leave",....,etc. Now I need to retrieve data, how many time an employee has requested for a leave on "earned_leave", "paid_leave",...,etc and reflect that number in the template.

*Update- I'm using the default dbsqlite3 db.

```
def leave_count(request):
        queryset = Leave.objects.filter(employee_ID = request.user.username, type_of_leave = 'Sick Leave')
        return render(request, "history.html", {'queryset' : queryset})
```

Since, I don't know how to query the db I've put in views.py. It didn't work.

Comment: custom `templatetags` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @serbia99 could you please give me an example wrt to them, I've tried but failed miserably.

Comment: What do you mean "I want to declare a local variable called 'el' and thereby increase it each time when it is called" ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers like without declaring `el` as a variable, how to increase it?

Comment: @Jose this makes no sense - you cannot increase a variable without having a variable. And this doesn't answer the question: what do you mean by "increase it each time when it is called" ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers okay, in the database if the user requests leaves in the name of 'el', I need to count the no. of times leaves were requested in the name of el(s).

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand a single word of what you are asking for. All you're code is doing is to count (in the least efficient way) how many instances of `My_model` exists where `My_model.emp_id` equals `request.user.username` (which is a bad idea in itself, you should use the user.id as foreign key, not the username) and  `My_model.leave` equals "earned_leave". How does this relate with "counting the number of time leaves where requested in the name of el(s)", whatever this might means ( and I'd really like to understand what this is supposed to mean).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers in simple words, leaves and username are two coloumns in db, How to count how many times a user has requested for a leave? and reflect in the template.

Comment: "How to count how many times a user has requested for a leave" => for which definition of "a user as requested for a leave" ? Please realize that someone that doesn't know your project cannot understand what this is supposed to mean (this is domain knowledge, not technical knowledge).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm working on "leave management system". I need to know how many time a user has requested for a leave. Initially a user sends a leave request form to the admin with ModelForms. There are leave types like "earned_leave",....,etc. Now I need to retrieve data, how many time an employee has requested for a leave on "earned_leave", "paid_leave",...,etc and reflect that number in the template. my bad for explaining the context.

Comment: Ok now please edit your post with all those clarifications.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I need to retrieve data, how many time an employee has requested for a leave on "earned_leave"

```
request.user.leave_set.filter(type_of_leave="Earned leave").count()
```

> "paid_leave" etc

If you want to retrieve the counts for each type of leave in a single SQL query:

```
from django.db.models import Count
queryset = request.user.leave_set.values("type_of_leave").annotate(count=Count("type_of_leave")).order_by("type_of_leave")
for item in queryset:
    print("{type_of_leave}: {count}".format(**item))
```

How to pass a variable (whatever it's type) to a template is pretty well documented so I won't give an example here.

Comment: I'm sorry where do I include this code? I have put this in my views.py, with a def name and mapped it with url. It didn't work, I did the same with models.py. No result. `leave_set` does it mean an object?

Comment: @Jose I'm sorry but SO is not a substitue for reading the docs and learning to use Python and Django. All this is extensively documented and there's no shortage of tutorials either.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this in models:

In your `Leave` - you are having `users` as foreign key.  At users side - in model, you can in fact write:

```
def get_el(self):
      el = 0
      for x in self.Leave.iterator():
             if x.type_of_leave == 'earned_leave':
                  el++
     return el
```

In your template  - you can actually  write `user.get_el` to render the leaves.

You need to use some concept called **"related_name"** . Also, you need to extend your **User** model appropriately.

Good Luck!

Comment: You have a SQL database, not a bit bucket. SQL database know how to count items etc...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have dbsqlite3 databse.